# Secure ways of running backend functionality on client side

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, backend

I have an application that sends some data to a backend on a webserver where that data is being analysed and put through a neural network to come back with some other data that is being displayed on the client front-end.

Now, when a lot of clients are connecting simultaneously, we have to scale up, and then down again + there is network latency and you always need an Internet connection.

Because the backend isn't doing that much, besides just analysing and putting data through a neural network... it would be ideal to put this backend functionality in each client... no more need to scale up (every client has his own backend on board) + no more network latency.

The problem is of course that the most valuable thing is the trained neural network data, that in this case should also be present on each client... and of course I don't want it to be stolen as it costed a lot of money to buy training data for our neural network + then we had to train it as well...

So my question is:

`Is there any way to run the backend neural network on the client side in a secure way, preventing our valuable trained neural network from being stolen?`

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no absolute way to prevent that, no.

If you give give a binary to be executed to a client, there will be ways for your client to copy it in some shape or form and execute it again.

Comment: I was wondering myself if encryption could be a solution? Where we do run a certificate server and the client has to renew the certificate every week f.ex. (then we can also disable licenses). Or is it not a good way of securing a local running backend?

Comment: @Geoffrey Binaries can't run encrypted, even if you imagine having files encrypted, and you would download a temporary key, well once it's loaded in memory you could make a memory snapshot, or corrupt the client so he dumps the decrypted NN file...

Comment: @Geoffrey Note that it's not saying you should not do it client side, its just saying if someone sufficiently tech savy wants the NN he will be able to and that is not really counterable other than not giving them the binary.